# docker view container contents on realtime

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker. I have run a web server on Docker, which creates files as per user request. While the Docker is running I want to view and read those files from Docker container. How can I do it from host ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first execute a shell inside your running container :

```
docker exec -i -t your_container /bin/sh
```

Then, from here, you should be able to view/read files existing inside the container.

If you want to access your files directly from your host, you can use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). For example, run your container like :

```
docker run -d \
    -v /path/on/your/host:/path/on/your/container \
    your_webserver_image
```

Then, created files inside your container (on folder `/path/on/your/container`) will then be accessible from your host (folder `/path/on/your/host`).